# How to stop Screen Space Overlay canvas from blocking UI button presses on World Space canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui, unity-components

I'm using Unity 2022.1.23f1 and the Universal Render Pipeline. I have a render texture, set to 480x270 with point filtering, to get a cool pixelated effect. In my scenes, I output the camera into the pixelated render texture and render it in a raw image under a Screen Space Overlay canvas. This makes it so that everything is rendered in 480x270.

Everything worked perfectly fine in the main gameplay, as there aren't any UI buttons to press. However, in my main menu scene I have three UI buttons for starting the game, accessing the options menu and quitting the game. The main menu is in 3D, featuring a desk with a monitor on it. I thought it would be cool to have the UI buttons look like they're on the monitor, which is why I made a World Space canvas, where I positioned the three UI buttons on the monitor.

I thought it would be easy to make the buttons interactable, but they don't work. I'm sure it's because the pixelation effect is blocking the UI buttons on the World Space canvas.

I removed the pixelation effect, along with the Screen Space Overlay canvas which holds it, and the buttons worked perfectly.

I googled the problem and found someone saying to remove the Graphic Raycaster component in the Scren Space Overlay Canvas, but that didn't work. I also turned off "Raycast Target" in the pixelation effect's raw image gameobject, but that also didn't work.

Is there any way to make it so that I can interact with the UI buttons in the World Space canvas, while also having the Screen Space Overlay canvas with the pixelation effect? Any help - or even suggestions to make a better pixelation effect - would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it’s the raycast that’s being blocked? My suspicion is that the coordinates of your click are actually nowhere near the actual buttons in world space. You’re viewing them on a vastly different scale. So I suspect the clicked position doesn’t actually hit the world space buttons cause they are not where they appear to be

Comment: Try outputting the button’s position and the click’s position. If they are vastly different that is your problem.